# ionic capacitor, Missing recommended icon

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, review

I have ionic capacitor app.
While uploading an app I received an email about "Missing recommended icon"
I got the following error from Apple, trying to add the files to the folder with all the other icons but still getting the same error.

Can anyone recommend a solution?
[Message from Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twupA.png)